# Properly normalizing a dual quaternion

Tags: quaternions, normalize

I'm having trouble with dual quaternions, and I believe it's because they're not properly normalized.
A, B and A' are dual quaternions where the latter is conjugated. When doing this:
Q = A * B * A'
I should theoretically always end up with Q = B if A and B are properly normalized. But in some cases, I don't, and it's completely messing up my whole skeletal hierarchy.

Many pages show that the norm of a dual quaternion is ||Q|| = sqrt(QQ'), but that means taking the square root of a dual number, and I have no idea how to do that. So right now I'm just dividing the whole thing by the length of the real part.

I've been searching around for days, but I still have yet to find a good code example on how to use dual quaternions. I feel I know the theory pretty well, but I still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

From glm source code:

```
template <typename T, precision P>
GLM_FUNC_QUALIFIER tdualquat<T, P> normalize(tdualquat<T, P> const & q)
{
    return q / length(q.real);
}
```

I checked the `operator/` implementation. It just divides both quaternions with a float.

Answer (score 0):

Not too difficult. Of interest for computer graphics are only unit dual quaternions, i.e. ||Q|| = 1. This leads to:

```
QQ' = (R, D)(R*, D*) = (RR*, RD* + DR*) = (1, 0)
```

Q = dual quaternion. R = real part, D = dual part. You see, for unit dual quaternions the dual part vanishes. You need only to calculate the magnitude for the real part. So the problem is reduced to calculating the magnitude of a simple quaternion. And that is calculated analogous as it is done for complex numbers:

```
||R|| = sqrt(r1^2+r2^2+r3^2+r4^2)
```

(r1 - r4 are the components of the 4D vector R)

Now just divide the R/||R|| and D/||R|| and you have your normalized Q.

Comment: This answer is incorrect - you can show that the new DQ does not have norm = 1 when you simply divide both constituent quaternions by the norm of the real part.

Answer (score 0):

I'm recently studying dual quaternion and just came across the same question, I'll try to give my answer, correct me if anything is wrong.

To normalize a dual quaternion, say Q=a+eb, we can just divide it by ||Q||. We need to calculate the norm of Q, this can be done with the following formula,

[image: norm of a dual quaternion]

Then we can calculate the normalization by

[image: normalize a dual quaternion]

Answer (score 0):

As the OP correctly notes, but none of the other answers correctly addresses, the squared norm **QQ*** of a dual quaternion **Q** is in general a dual number. That is

**QQ* = s + tε**

In order for **QQ*** to equal **1**, we must have **s=1** AND **t=0**. The **t=0** part is being ignored in the other answers but this poses an extra condition on the coefficients that we should incorporate. To correctly normalize our **Q** we need to divide by the square root of **QQ***. Hence we should calculate the inverse square root of a dual number. This is given, for a dual number of the form **s + tε** by

**u = 1/√s**

**1/√(s + tε) = u - tu³/2 ε**

The proof of the above follows from direct calculation. We first square the expression:

**(u - tu³/2 ε)(u - tu³/2 ε) = u² - tu⁴**

substituting **u** back to **1/√s** and multiplying with **s + tε** we find

**u² - tu⁴ = (1/s - t/s² ε)**

**(1/s - t/s² ε)(s + tε) = s/s + t/s ε - t/s ε = 1**

as required. This new dual number **u - tu³/2 ε** can now trivially be multiplied with **Q** to produce a normalized **Q** which will correctly satisfy **QQ* = 1 + 0ε = 1**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for your descriptive answer! I do wonder how you found this question from over nine years ago though! I did find a solution in the end, went ahead and made my own skeletal animation software which I used for several games, but programming stayed nothing more than a hobby and I became a dentist instead. I still dabble, and join the occasional game jam from time to time though!