# dual number magnitude and normalization

Tags: math, quaternions

I need help figuring out how to calculate the magnitude of a dual number and then how to use it to normalize the number.

The closest answer I found was this: [Properly normalizing a dual quaternion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174899/properly-normalizing-a-dual-quaternion)

However, there is either an error there or (more likely) I do not understand the notation.  The reply to that post states that the magnitude of a *unit* dual quaternion (still a form of a dual number) is as follows:

```
QQ' = (R, D)(R*, D*) = (RR*, RD* + DR*) = (1, 0)
```

Note that this is a dual number, not a single value.  I have seen this same result in many articles on dual quaternions, but none of them explain why the dual number is 0 (zero).

I assume that, if a dual quaternion is normalized, then its real and dual component quaternions are also normalized.  In this case, the quaternion conjugate is equivalent to it's inverse, and RR* does indeed = 1.  But if they are *not* normalized, then RR* does not = 1, so what do I do then?

Additionally, RD* + DR* is not 0 (unless I'm reading the notation wrong), but rather

```
RD* + DR* = [2(R.scalar)(D*.scalar) + 2dot(R.vector,D.vector), <0,0,0>]
```

which is a quaternion with non-zero scalar and a "zero vector", so to speak.  This quaternion is certainly not of magnitude 0.

Besides, the wiki on dual quaternions, this blog post (be very careful when reading the terms, because he uses bold q's and normal q's and q's with subscripts for dual quaternions, quaternions, and real numbers, which is terribly confusing, but it is correct: http://simonstechblog.blogspot.com/2011/11/dual-quaternion.html), and my own calculations confirmed that a dual number times it's conjugate is another dual number, NOT a single value.

Do I divide the dual number by it's dual number magnitude to normalize?  How does that work?  I'm stuck.

Comment: Good question, but maybe better suited for [Math.SE]

Comment: Thanks.  I'll try posting there.